# How to run multiple bitcoin RPC commands through the command window?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

Yes, I can generate a new address through the bitcoin-qt command console, but how might I run a for loop to generate 100 different addresses? What kind of file does the bitcoin client take?

Can I run a python script through the bitcoin command console?

How exactly does sending multiple commands to a command prompt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, I can generate a new address through the bitcoin-qt command console, but how might I run a for loop to generate 100 different addresses? What kind of file does the bitcoin client take?

You can't. It only accepts specific API commands as described [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) or by calling the `help` command in that dialog.

> Can I run a python script through the bitcoin command console?

If by the "bitcoin command console" you refer to `QT`'s dialog then no, you can't. You can run a script from your console, though, if you have Python installed in your system or go for a more elegant approach a use a proper [RPC API wrapper](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#Python).

> How exactly does sending multiple commands to a command prompt work?

It has already been answer above.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly does sending multiple commands to a command prompt work?

Are you asking about [shell scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) in general? If you know how to send one command through the Bitcoin command-line interface, performing multiple commands is just writing a script to do it multiple times - in this case you can't do it at the application level.

> Can I run a python script

Yes, use [python-bitcoinlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bitcoinlib), which is now maintained by Peter Todd, and is available by pip.